# set number of file write attempts in spark context

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm running pyspark inside of aws glue jobs.  As part of my pyspark script I write pyspark dataframes to a directory as parquet files.  I would like to modify my spark context so that it will try to write each parquet file to the directory at least 20 times before failing the whole dataframe write attempt.  The original version I have of starting my code is below.  I've updated the "updated" version below as I think I'm supposed to in order to modify the spark context and use it with the glue context.  Can someone please tell me if I've done this correctly or let me know how to fix it?  Thanks

Original:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

spark = glueContext.spark_session
```

updated:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

sc = SparkContext()
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.maxretries", "20")

glueContext = GlueContext(sc.getOrCreate())

spark = glueContext.spark_session
```

Comment: this could also do the same thing

`glueContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.maxretries", "20")`

Answer (score 0):

Your updated code looks right
You can validate if the property is set by printing out the value from the below method

```
sc.getConf().getAll()
```

Comment: By doing that you don't know if it's an hadoop setting that has been changed or a Spark setting, best is to use the SparkUI tool